# ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError because of schema cache in sidekiq server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, amazon-ecs, sidekiq

I have two servers in my application;
・server for web request(server 1)
・server for sidekiq process(server 2)

One day I added a new column to database by migration file and deployed it to two servers.
my servers are on AWS ECS(Fargate), so task will be recreated by releasing.

After I deployed it, I got an error;  "ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError".
When I investigated, the reason why I got this error might be;

① deploy on server 2 was completed
② deploy on server 1 was completed and web server restarted with running command `rails db:migrate`
③ since schema cache on server 2 cannot see newly added column in ②, so ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError occurs.

First idea I came up with to solve this is to run ① after ③ completed, but I could not find the way on AWS ECS.

Can I handle this on rails application or AWS?

Sorry for my poor English and Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are both containers running in the same ECS task, or in completely separate ECS tasks/services? I typically run sidekiq as a sidecar container in the same task as the primary server. If they are in the same task you can specify that one container depends on the other, so that you can be sure one always starts first.

Comment: thank you for your comment, I am using completely separate ECS tasks/services because their commands are different(the former is booting sidekiq and the latter is starting puma).    sorry, I am not familiar to sidecar container. is it a kind of setting on ECS?

Comment: There's no reason you have to separate the containers into separate tasks just because the commands are different. Sidecar containers is just the name of a pattern for having multiple containers in a task, it's not specific to ECS.